# foreach in php is treating all pictures the same

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, rating, rating-system

I made a foreach loop, but I can only vote for the first movie post. If I try to vote for the other images, the changes are not reflected and I am able to see only the changes made to the first post.

```
   <?php foreach($imgsqlResults as $imgre): ?>
      <?php 
      $sql2 =  "SELECT * FROM posts";
      $result2  =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
      while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
       $postid        = $rows['post_id'];
       $post_owner    = $rows['user_unam'];
       $post_pic_path = $rows['pic_path'];
      }
      ?>
             <div class='postsContainer' id='<?php echo $postid ?>'>
                <div class='profile-cont'>
                    <div class='who-post'>
                    <div class='who-post-name'><a href='$imgrefrence'>Marwan Mason</a></div>
                    <div class='who-post-img'><img src='photos/<?php echo $imgre['pic_path'] ?>'></div>
                  </div>

                       <div class='img-ctn'><img src='photos/<?php echo $imgre['pic_path'] ?>'></div>
                        <div class='star-rating'>
                    <form method='POST' >
                    <input type='h' name='imgId<?php echo $imgre['id'];?>' value="<?php echo $imgre['id'];?>"> 
                    <input id='star-1' type='radio' name='rating' value='star-5'>
                    <label for='star-1' title='Perfection'></label>
                    <input id='star-2' type='radio' name='rating' value='star-4'>
                    <label for='star-2' title='Amazing'></label>
                    <input id='star-3' type='radio' name='rating' value='star-3'>
                    <label for='star-3' title='wow'></label>
                    <input id='star-4' type='radio' name='rating' value='star-2'>
                    <label for='star-4' title='Nice'></label>
                    <input id='star-5' type='radio' name='rating' value='star-1'>
                    <label for='star-5' title='Not Bad'></label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
                  </form>
                  </div>


      </div>
      </div>
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       if(isset($_POST['rating'])){
         echo "You have selected ";
         }else{ echo "<span>Please choose any radio button.</span>";}
         }


               ?>
          <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: if your `<form>` is in a loop, then you will non-unique `id`s, as each loop will create duplicates.

Comment: what do i gotta do ?

Comment: you need to make the `id`s and inputs specific to each movie. Show how you are creating/showing each movie post

Comment: i don't how to do that

Comment: Where is your `for each` ?

Comment: ive posted it now look on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can:** *(Although I don't recommend your coding pattern)*

Make unique the ids for your each form in `foreach`.

Make all `form` & `input` unique (or atleast the ability to handle them separately).

**like this**

```
<?php
foreach ($imgsqlResults AS $key => $item) {
    ?>
    <div class='postsContainer'>
        <div class='profile-cont'>
            <div class='who-post'>
                <div class='who-post-name'><a href='$imgrefrence'> Marwan Mason </a></div>
                <div class='who-post-img'><img src='photos/<?php echo $item['pic_path'] ?>'></div>
            </div>

            <div class='img-ctn'><img src='photos/<?php echo $item['pic_path'] ?>'></div>
            <div class='star-rating'>

                <form method='POST'>
                    <!-- This unique_id is to handle each form separately -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="unique_id" value="<?= $item['your_record_primary'] ?>"/>

                    <!-- This your_record_primary will make every input name unique -->
                    <input id='star-1<?= $key ?>' type='radio' name='rating<?= $item['your_record_primary'] ?>'
                           value='star-5'>
                    <label for='star-1' title='Perfection'></label>
                    <input id='star-2<?= $key ?>' type='radio' name='rating<?= $item['your_record_primary'] ?>'
                           value='star-4'>
                    <label for='star-2' title='Amazing'></label>
                    <input id='star-3<?= $key ?>' type='radio' name='rating<?= $item['your_record_primary'] ?>'
                           value='star-3'>
                    <label for='star-3' title='wow'></label>
                    <input id='star-4<?= $key ?>' type='radio' name='rating<?= $item['your_record_primary'] ?>'
                           value='star-2'>
                    <label for='star-4' title='Nice'></label>
                    <input id='star-5<?= $key ?>' type='radio' name='rating<?= $item['your_record_primary'] ?>'
                           value='star-1'>
                    <label for='star-5' title='Not Bad'></label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && (!empty($_POST['unique_id']) && $_POST['unique_id'] === $item['your_record_primary'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['rating' . $item['your_record_primary']])) {
            echo "<span>You have selected :<b> " . $_POST['rating' . $item['your_record_primary']] . "</b></span>";
        } else {
            echo "<span>Please choose any radio button.</span>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

`id='star-1<?= $key?>'` will essentially give you:

```
<!-- First iteration will look like -->
<input id='star-10 />
.
.
<input id='star-50 />
<!-- Next iteration will look like -->
<input id='star-11 />
.
.    
<input id='star-51 />
```

**NOTE:** If you're using the `id` properties of these `input` elements in your JS perhaps you must find a way to handle these dynamic `ids`.

**Explanation:**

Since in your code `if(isset($_POST['submit'])` is inside the loop.

We need to evaluate true **ONLY** for the right `if(isset($_POST['submit'])` on submitting the form, and to achieve that we introduce and additional input `<input type="hidden" name="unique_id" value="<?= $item['your_record_primary'] ?>"/>`to maintain the uniqueness.

**We then replace** `if(isset($_POST['submit'])`

**with** `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && (!empty($_POST['unique_id']) && $_POST['unique_id'] === $item['your_record_primary']))`. So that  only the request with the right `unique_id` gets insides its if condition. Hope I made myself clear enough.

Comment: @MarwanMason Check my updated code and let me know you need anything futher.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: your_record_primary in

Comment: (-_-)  Seriously ? you need to **put your DB primary key column name** here.  Don't just copy paste my code, read it understand the logic and then make the necessary changes.

Comment: is this another way to make rating stars ?

Comment: sorry bro xD but please explain im just a noob

Comment: Yes, of-course there are. You need to research about it on the web. The whole **`isset($_POST['submit'])` and form inside a loop** is one of the worst approach to register rating.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial if you can work with **jquery** and **AJAX** : [Building a 5 Star Rating System With jQuery, AJAX and PHP](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php--net-11541)

Comment: $imgsqlResults returns the image path wish is random numbers .jpg

Comment: what do you mean by $item['your_record_primary'] what am i supposed to replace it with

Comment: You're fetching  `$imgsqlResults` from a DB table, right? If yes replace it with your db table's primary key.

Comment: the problem is the when i added id='star-3<?= $key ?>' and clicked the stars they  didnt show the clicking effect but when i deleted the <?= $key ?> it worked

Comment: bro it worked i added the <?= $key ?> to the label too then it worked thanks a lot

Comment: @MarwanMason That's great, accept it as answer. You're Welcome :)

Comment: Am updating it in my answer, but confirm me something. Do you want to know the role and logic of the above input in the code. right ?

Comment: Check the explanation in my answer at the end and please consider accepting it as answer. Thanks

Comment: sorry im just new

Comment: Its okay, we all have been there.

Comment: i removed the submit button i want to rate without submitting but i don't how its like it doesn't work without the submit button

Comment: You can use `<a href="rating.php?movie_id=your_movie_id&rating=5" ></a>` _Though, It will be susceptible to SQL injection you need to take care of that_

Comment: well the reason why i was confused is cause i thought that id is only for css now i understand better

Comment: @MarwanMason Great, always make that you never duplicate an id on single webpage.

Comment: so i learned ajax but i don't know how to insert all of the stars value to the db all i managed to do is to insert the value of the first star i don't know how to do that, i searched but didn't find anything and everyone uses jquery while i use javaScript

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
   <html>
<body>
<form method='POST'>
                  <input id='star-1' type='radio' name='rating[]' value='star-5'>
                  <label for='star-1' title='Perfection'></label>
                  <input id='star-2' type='radio' name='rating[]' value='star-4'>
                  <label for='star-2' title='Amazing'></label>
                  <input id='star-3' type='radio' name='rating[]' value='star-3'>
                  <label for='star-3' title='wow'></label>
                  <input id='star-4' type='radio' name='rating[]' value='star-2'>
                  <label for='star-4' title='Nice'></label>
                  <input id='star-5' type='radio' name='rating[]' value='star-1'>
                  <label for='star-5' title='Not Bad'></label>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
                </form>


</body> 
</html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     if(isset($_POST['rating'])){

       echo "<span>You have selected :<b> ".$_POST['rating'][0]."</b></span>";
       }else{ echo "<span>Please choose any radio button.</span>";}
       }
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: `isset($_POST['submit']` is in the loop any submit request will give **TRUE** to all of the `isset($_POST['submit']` .

Comment: the problem is still the same it treats them as one post
if i vote for the other pictures only the first one changes

Comment: you want all radio button value right?if yes then you will write $_POST['rating'] in loop

Comment: non i want each picture to have its own rating cause all of the other images don't work only the first image

Comment: can you give me url ?

Comment: i think you have to pass image id in hidden text box

Comment: i don't have the url yet but how can i past the id please i think that's what i need

Comment: can you print_r($imgre); send me database for particular this

Comment: Please choose any radio button. Array ( [id] => 66 [user_id] => 45 [user_unam] => mar1 [pic_path] => mar15a7163d395a931.22084405.png )

Comment: <input  type='text' name='imgId<?php echo $imgre['id'];?>' value="<?php echo $imgre['id'];?>">

Comment: i added that code but it only added an input with id

Comment: i think this put id  
<input type='text' name='imgId<?php echo $imgre['id'];?>' value="<?php echo $imgre['id'];?>">